# Keras IMDB dataset load_data function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

Can anyone explain how does the `tf.keras.datasets.imdb.load_data()` converts the reviews into index with an example.

What does the num_words, index_start parameter do?
I have read the documentation and cannot understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The Documentation is located here

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/imdb/load_data

it states    "num_words     integer or None. Words are ranked by how often they occur (in the training set) and only the num_words most frequent words are kept. Any less frequent word will appear as oov_char value in the sequence data. If None, all words are kept. Defaults to None, so all words are kept."

I had just spent a long time figuring out something similar but unrelated.

Sometimes searching the code for comments next to the part you trying to figure out can help. Also, you can find things like keyword = other-keyword and then see the other keyword is the answer.

I looked at a Keras IMDb code real quick and same methods worked on that example not sure if it same IMDb Keras example you looked at as many people play with the dataset in many ways.

num_words is usually given 10,000 you are training based on the number of top words.

```
#num_words would be equal to top 10000 words

top_words = 10000
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(path="imdb.npz",
                                                      num_words=top_words

# INDEX_START as first element in sequence (keras convention)


INDEX_START=1

def preprocess_imdb(review):
    # clean and tokenize
    words_list = text_to_word_sequence(review)
    # init array
    words_index_list = []
    # INDEX_START as first element in sequence (keras convention)
    words_index_list.append(INDEX_START)
    #words_index_list[0] = INDEX_START
```